# Angular2: can change detection be different per each level component?

Tags: angular

In Angular2, can change detection be different per each level component?
In other words if I have

```
comp1 detection onPush
     comp2 detection onPush
          comp3 detection default
               comp4 detection onPush
```

if I apply changes to comp3, will it not update the UI unless comp2 changes?
The reason I am asking is becuase I am seeing a strange behavior and I am thinking maybe its the fault of the parents components...

so in other words, can you MIX ChangeDetection Strategies checking at diff levels of the component tree? and the framework via zone.js will be smart enough to handle each detection per its assigned value? (I am sure seeing some strange update behaviors when I do that.. err: Uncaught Attempt to use a dehydrated detector: UserInfo_0)

for reference: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6786
thanks

Sean

Comment: I don't see why not. Are you specifying `changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.something` on each component level?

Comment: yes I am... seems like more people seeing this issue: PR 6786

Answer (score 4):

A [recent blog post](http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/02/22/angular-2-change-detection-explained.html) by Pascal Precht explained Angular2 change detection in depth.

By my understanding of the explanation, changes in comp3 will indeed not be detected unless comp2 changes. In fact, they won't be detected unless both comp2 *and comp1* change. When a component is marked with on push change detection strategy, that drops its entire subtree out unless that component's inputs change.

There is a way around this, however, detailed near the end of the blog post. In comp3, inject a `ChangeDetectorRef` and store it. Then set up a handler for whatever event causes comp3's data to change, or use an `Observable` for the data itself, if you don't have one already, and in that handler call `markForCheck()` on the `ChangeDetectorRef`. This will inform Angular2 that something in comp3 has changed, and the next time change detection runs it will check the path from the root to comp3 regardless of on push settings.

Comment: here is another useful doc: http://blog.jhades.org/how-does-angular-2-change-detection-really-work/

Comment: "This will inform Angular2 that something in comp3 has changed, and it will run change detection once on the path from the root to comp3 regardless of on push settings" -- I would word it slightly differently: `markForCheck()` marks the current component and all ancestor components up to the root component such that they will be checked the next time change detection runs.  (The way it is currently worded makes it sound like `markForCheck()` will cause change detection to execute.  It doesn't.  I just marks the path up to the root.)

Answer (score 0):

so in order for me to solve the issue I had to first turn off onPush detection which makes sense since I am updating a component internally and not through one of its inputs: removed the changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush

But, I also had to force a change detection via

```
constructor(private appStore:AppStore, private businessActions:BusinessAction, private ref:ChangeDetectorRef) {

 ....

updateUi() {
    try {
        this.ref.detectChanges();
    } catch (e) {
    }
}
```

which still I am not sure why I have to, as the component I am updating the value to is a child component and specified in my template, so change detection should kick in even without the ref.detectChanges()... but this does seem to solve the problem. I did have to wrap it in a catch to avoid a stack pending call on a destroyed reference while navigation away...

and given the fact I am using a string as the input for my child component and strings (primitives) in JS are immutable, the child component should have updated its UI...

hopes this helps someone...